# SwiftUI ScrollView also triggering DragGesture

Tags: swiftui

I'm making swipeable flash cards that a user fills in with their own content. The card contains a vertical ScrollView (for text) and horizontal ScrollView (for tags). The card also has a drag gesture attached to it. However, when I'm scrolling through the ScrollViews it also triggers the DragGesture's .onChanged (but also doesn't even follow with .onEnded). How can I prioritize the ScrollView before the gesture?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var translation: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Color(.blue).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        Text("blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah")
                    }
                    Tags(decks: ["Tag", "Tag", "Tag", "Tag", "Tag", "Tag", "Tag"])
                }

                .padding(24)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 48, height: geometry.size.height / 2)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18, style: .continuous))
                .animation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.75, blendDuration: 0))
                .offset(x: self.translation.width, y: self.translation.height)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        self.translation = value.translation
                    }.onEnded { value in
                        self.translation = .zero
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Tags: View {
    var decks: [String] = []

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(decks, id: \.self) { deck in
                    Text(deck)
                        .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .semibold))
                        .padding(.vertical, 6)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: card gesture activated while scrolling through scrollview]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @erkutbas I didn't unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

try using gesture modifiers, such as simultaneously(with:), sequenced(before:) or exclusively(before:) to address you problem.

Comment: If I understand what I am finding online, those are for two gestures I implement myself but I'm only adding the one DragGesture. However, I assume ScrollView has some sort of gesture built into it but I'm not sure how to reference it to be used in the modifiers you've suggested.